# Pass label value to progress bar value property in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, progress-bar, htmlgenericcontrol

I am using a progress bar in my web project. I want to add label value getting from Code Behind to progress bar' data-percent value property. However, I am getting error such as:

> *Error    217 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text'
> accepting a first argument of type
> 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Codes are like this:

```
<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="<asp:Label ID="lblYuzde" runat="server"></asp:Label>%">
 <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #c0392b;"><span>TOPLAM</span>
 </div>
   <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e74c3c;"></div>
   <div class="skill-bar-percent"><asp:Label ID="lblBlogAdet" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="navy" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label></div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of Progress Bar]

Would you help me please to fix the problem in a simple way?

Comment: string a = system.GetDataCell("SELECT * FROM TABLE'");
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
lblYuzde.Text = b.ToString();
lblBlogAdet.Text = b.ToString();

Comment: It's underlies lblYuzde.Text in code behind

Comment: if you have more info, please use the "edit" feature of the question to add it, format it properly and put it in context, instead of pasting unformatted stuff into the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You are essentially putting a `span` inside a `data-percent`. You should do this sort of thing from the Code Behind.

If you want to put the value into the `data-percent` attribute, I'd do something like this.

**ASPX Page**

```
<div class="skillbar clearfix" runat="server" id="progressBar"></div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
progressBar.Attributes.Add("data-percent", "your-value");
```

See [here for more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx).